# php artisan migrate error in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to create migration table in my particular path

```
php artisan make:migration create_options_table --create=site_options --path='Nitseditor/Nitseditor/Database'
```

I'm getting an error

> [ErrorException]
>
> Array to string conversion

My directory structure:

[image]

Help me out in this.

Comment: probably an error in your code that blocks artisan

Comment: check `web.php`. Should not have an error.

Comment: See if adding `-vvv` to your artisan command gives you a more detailed error: `php artisan make:migration -vvv ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is always hard to have just `Exception` without knowing what file should I check and which line.

First check logs `tail storage/logs/laravel.log -n 100` to get a trace of an exception thrown. There you will find the key to solve your problem. Example:

```
[2017-02-03 22:44:53] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 
<message> in <path>:<line>
Stack trace: ...<details>
```

Comment: I was looking for this thing. Thanks!